# Is there a way to query pyface for the active backend?

Tags: backend, pyface

Is there a way to find out which backend pyface is currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from traits.trait_base import ETSConfig
print ETSConfig.toolkit
```

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without explanation or context is not good. In it's current state your answer might not help other people who are looking for an answer to this question in the future.

Comment: While your admonishment is clearly well meaning, I completely disagree with it. The question is about what API call to use to query a somewhat obscure library that bridges components together. In my answer this information is succinctly provided. In fact the entire point of posting here is to help people who might be looking for an answer to this question in the future.

Comment: I realise that but answers on Stack Overflow are expected to be more than just a code dump. In it's current state your answer will not survive. I came across it in the first place because it was already flagged as low quality. Just adding one or two sentences like "You can try this:" or "This will do ..." is enough.

Comment: If it is deemed to be too low quality -- despite being a correct if possibly incomplete answer to a straightforward and somewhat obscure question -- then the collective moderation of the site should feel free to delete it. I would be pissed if that happened, because it is not a bad answer (it is also not a great answer).

Comment: I fail to see how adding "You can try this" would add to the quality of the answer. It is filler. It would not substantively improve the answer. If a person reviewed this answer and decided that it is a "bad" answer because it consists only of code necessary to answer the question, then in my opinion they made a mistake. If it is not deleted, I will add new information to this answer if and when I find new useful information to add.

Comment: Well that's why I didn't recommend deletion but left a comment instead. I'm just saying that this answer could use improvement and if it stays in its current state it might be deleted at some point in the future.

Comment: In my opinion conciseness is a good thing, thanks @ aestrivex!